# A sentence starting with "кому надо"

Tags: грамматика

If I write "Кому надо послать деньги?" does that mean

a) To whom must the money be sent? - or

b) Who must send the money?

Or is the sentence ambiguous?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** Let me clarify that answers in Russian are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit ambiguous, and may indeed mean both (theoretically), depending on context:

- To whom should I send the money?
- Who *has to/want to* send the money?

However, the latter is rather unlikely in normal situations, but might come useful if these is somethin unusual about the transfer, i.e. it matters who exactly sends the money.

Or if you asked a friend a rather general question about transferring money, so they are interested who exactly needs their money to be sent ("Кому надо послать деньги" sounds rather informal for a question from the official support).

From a pragmatic point of view, I'd avoid using the phrase in the 2nd meaning if a person answering it is not particularly familiar with situation. Or if they answer similar questions ten times a day. The reason is exactly the "most likely" interpretation: if a person hears something like that out of the blue, they will probably analyze it according to *"send - something - to someone"* scheme. For the second meaning to activate, a person has to know that the addressee is already known (so you would not ask that again).

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is ambiguous. In a written text usually only (1) is acceptable. But in everyday talk (or in a book if the author tries to imitate the spoken language) you may encounter both variants differing in intonation.

Comment: Would it be a mistake then to write "Ему надо поесть" in a formal context? And "Кому надо поесть?" Or does the problem with (b) arise solely because of the potential ambiguity?

Comment: @Dave, the issue with your example is its syntactic ambiguity, which for *semantic* reasons is likely to resolved in favour of (a). There are other examples, like of «Кому надо уступить дорогу?» that are more likely to be interpreted as "who has to leave the way", and the other meaning would require a special intonation or some other hints.

Comment: @J-mster Thanks. That explanation clarifies things a great deal.

Comment: @Dave Actually "Ему надо поесть" or "Кому надо поесть" are both _inambiguous_ as "поесть" can't be used with dative so one reads "кому надо" only - who needs/wants. (Well, to say the truth, sometimes people may say "кому поесть?" but it's just shortened "кому дать поесть?"). Unlike this "Кому надо послать" may be understood either "_Кому послать_-то надо?" or "_Кому надо_-то послать?"

Answer (score 2):

> Кому надо послать деньги?

В разговоре смысл этой фразы может зависеть от контекста.

Наиболее вероятный вариант - вопрос о человеке-получателе.
*Я иду в банк, напомни, кому надо послать дельги (кто получатель).*

Другие возможные варианты:
*Кому(-то) надо послать деньги? Проходите без очереди.* - про отправителя.
*Кому(-нибудь) надо послать деньги? Я иду в банк, пойдёмте вместе.* - про отправителя.

В любом случае, перевод *Who must send the money?* мне кажется неправильным. Для этого варианта скорее должно быть *is going to* или *wants to*. Вариант *Who must send the money?* я понимаю как *Чья обязанность послать деньги?* *Кто должен послать деньги?*

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: да, двусмысленно.

---

Предложенный Вами случай не специфичен.

```
Вы автор книги «Анна Каренина»?
 1. Вы — автор?
 2. Этой книги, или другой?


Диаметр круга пять сантиметров?
 1. Пять, a не шесть сантиметров?
 2. Именно круга? А может, кольца?
```

Мы пишем для того, чтобы нас *правильно* поняли. **Двусмысленность является ошибкой** в передаче сообщения. Исключением будет поэзия, где мы наоборот, желаем, чтобы фантазия читателя улетела далеко-далеко :)

OP case is not special:

```
Вы автор книги «Анна Каренина»?
 1. You're the author of the book «Анна Каренина», aren't you? 
    I said, no, the author is Tolstoy.
 2. Are you an author, if I am not mistaken, of the book «Анна Каренина» or something?

Диаметр круга пять сантиметров? 
 1. What is the diameter of the circle? 
    They asked me how big. I said, 5 cm in diameter.
 2. The diameter of what of? Of a circle, or possible, a ring?
```

It is evident that OP case is not special, but a very ordinary case.

Poetry is famous for its haziness. But for most writing, ***Ambiguity is a weakness.*** There is a plently cases also in English. Try searching for Ambiguity in the Web. For example:

```
They were entertaining guests.  
  This sentence is ambiguous because the reader 
  does not know if the guests were amusing or 
  if people were giving hospitality to guests.
```

Comment: В том случае, как передать первый смысл самым простым образом?

Comment: @Dave , (1) `Кому отправить деньги?` или `Кому будем отправлять деньги?` (2) `Кто отправляет деньги?` или `Кто обязан/должен отправить деньги?`

Comment: А значит, для первого смысла, достаточно опустить слово « надо »? Например, «Кому послать деньги?».

Comment: @Dave , В общем, да, достаточно, слово `надо(нужно)` опустить. Но  `послать денег` стоит в том же ряду, что `послать гостинцев (внучке)`. Сегодня устойчивый оборот [`отправить деньги`](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EE%F2%EF%F0%E0%E2%E8%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=10&lex2=%E4%E5%ED%FC%E3%E8&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)

Comment: @Dave , сравнить: [`послать деньги`](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EF%EE%F1%EB%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=10&lex2=%E4%E5%ED%FC%E3%E8&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)

Comment: Спасибо!........

Comment: @Dave, The syntactic ambiguity does not depend on «надо».    To completely eliminate it, you should either avoid the word "кому" (e g, «На чей адрес послать деньги?») or specify the subject («кому я должен послать деньги?»)

Comment: @J-mster I am afraid the absolute ambiguity regardless of "надо" does not apply to the real Russian language. Statistically "Кому послать деньги?" requires some some miracle to be understood as something other than "to whom..". I cannot even think of a situation when it may be interpreted that way. Usually the infinitive statement implies that an action "should be" performed by a known individual or in general (by any person). That leaves only one interpretation for "кому". The interpretation would be different for a verb that does not have a Dative "receiver".

Comment: @Shady_arc that's why I was referring to _syntactic_ ambiguity. I can easily think about situations where similar questions (like _кому придется уступить?_) may refer to the subject. In this case, you are right, it is hard to misinterpret the question - but only because of semantics / pragmatics.

Comment: @J-mster You mean, "Кому уступить?" might be understood as "Who should give in"? I don't think that works either. Maybe that depends on the region. To a degree, the ambiguity works for me in "Кому уступить дорогу?", though, that might have something to do with the fact that a sentence sounds unnatural—and the interpretation does not matter (if one of the participants gives way, the other is being given way to). However, when I think of verbs that allow different interpretations (давать, служить, говорить, послать, стричь волосы, верить), that other option just vanishes.